# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'login'

Tags: python, django

I have created application "login"

django-admin.py startapp login

In settings.py, I added the app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login',
]
```

my views.py file content

```
#views.py
from login.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'registration/register.html',
    variables,
    )

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'registration/success.html',
    )

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


@login_required
def home(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'home.html',
    { 'user': request.user }
    )
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from login.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
    url(r'^register/$', register),
    url(r'^register/success/$', register_success),
    url(r'^home/$', home),

)
```

When i start the app,

```
(project) H:\Django\myapp>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x05CDD9C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kalu\Envs\project\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'login'
```

I have tried to follow along some django tutorials to create a login but i keep getting this error when i start the server. Can someone help to resolve this ?

Comment: Could you please post the tree structure of your project, I think the problem is there.

Comment: Thanks. yes. It a problem with hierarchy. I fixed it. But after accesing my URL, I am getting below error with post request.                                                           Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.  Can you suggest , how to fix this ?

Comment: Maybe you should update your question, I'm answering this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your directory structure and after fixing that, you should do the following for 403:

For CSRF verification, you've most likely forgotten to add

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

to your form.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Check your tree structure.
Your directory structure should be similar to this -

```
C:login/
│   admin.py
│   apps.py
│   forms.py
│   models.py
│   tests.py
│   views.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───migrations
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│
├───templates
│   └───login
│           index.html
│           login.html
│
└───__pycache__
        admin.cpython-37.pyc
        forms.cpython-37.pyc
        models.cpython-37.pyc
        views.cpython-37.pyc
        __init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

Summary: Check your login folder, it should have forms.py